# Handling Cusom Key Board Types in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

Here in (http://iosfonts.com/) this site, number of fonts are listed that iOS devices supports. For an Indian language, Tamil, there is a font named Sangam. My understanding is that there is no Localization support for the languages Tamil, Telugu or Devanagiri. As iOS supports TTF and OpenType fonts both to be added to the XCode, Is it possible to create a custom keyboard lay out, for typing using these fonts. As these languages has no similarities with any of the language keyboard that apple supports presently, is there a way to type, store and share the text contents using these custom type fonts.

Comment: I can see that your question is no longer a duplicate, but you should really update the title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply embed the font files (.ttf or .otf files) in your app then add them to the list of the dedicated `UIAppFonts` key in your `Info.plist` file *(Note: the key is called "Fonts provided by application" in its human-readable description)*.
See [the doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18).

You can then simply use `[UIFont fontWithName:size:]` with the name of your custom font to manipulate the font and affect it to your labels and so on.